# Android Studio extremely slow sync for downloading kotlin compiler embeddable 1.5.0.jar

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a student from South Korea. Sorry for my poor english skil.
I try to build android studio language based on kotlin.
But the sync speed is very very slow...
It takes 2 hours and 30 minutes.. but still downloading status.
I tried offline mode but it failed...
How can i solve this problem... Please hele me... I want to study kotlin!

Comment: What's the system specifications?

Comment: My notebook spec is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz and 16GB RAM and 4GB geforce gtx